# How can I write the following script in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So the program that I wanna write is about adding two strings S1 and S2 who are made of int.
example: S1='129782004977', S2='754022234930', SUM='883804239907'
So far I've done this but still it has a problem because it does not rive me the whole SUM.

```
def addS1S2(S1,S2):
    N=abs(len(S2)-len(S1))
    if len(S1)<len(S2):
        S1=N*'0'+S1
    if len(S2)<len(S1):
        S2=N*'0'+S2
    #the first part was to make the two strings with the same len.
    S=''
    r=0
    for i in range(len(S1)-1,-1,-1):
        s=int(S1[i])+int(S2[i])+r
        if s>9:
            r=1
            S=str(10-s)+S
        if s<9:
            r=0
            S=str(s)+S
            print(S)

        if r==1:
            S=str(r)+S

    return S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be homework, so I will not give full code but just a few pointers.

There are three problems with your algorithm. If you fix those, then it should work.

1. `10-s` will give you negative numbers, thus all those `-` signs in the sum. Change it to `s-10`
2. You are missing all the `9`s. Change `if s<9:` to `if s<=9:`, or even better, just `else:`
3. You should not add `r` to the string in *every* iteration, but just at the very end, after the loop.

Also, instead of using those convoluted `if` statements to check `r` and substract 10 from `s` you can just use division and modulo instead: `r = s/10` and `s = s%10`, or just `r, s = divmod(s, 10)`.

If this is *not* homework: Just use `int(S1) + int(S2)`.

Comment: Thank you.This is not a homework I'm just doing it for fun :)
the first 2 mistakes I've already fixed them, but the the last one is the one that I've been missing! Thanks for your help.
and I can not use int(S1)+int(S2) because it's actually the point of this whole program is that python does not support number out of this interval [-2147483648,2147483648] so we have to stock the int in str first.

Comment: @user3765119 Glad I could help. But what do you meant with "python does not support number out of this interval [-2147483648,2147483648]"? You can create a number like `123456789123456789123456789` with no problem, turn it into a string, back to an int, do calculations with it, etc. You can even do `len(str(2**2**2**2**2))`, which gives you `19729`. Are you using a special version or module of Python that does not support this?